# location of the .htaccess file for a Play Framework application served on Apache Webserver

Tags: .htaccess, playframework, apache2

I have a `Play Framework` application running on `localhost:9000` which is served with `apache2` as a proxy frontal server as documented in [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/HTTPServer), redirecting all the requests to `Play`.

I need to edit the directory `.htaccess` file for adding a few restrictions with respect to the ip and the url with which the various HTTP requests are made.

Where can I put this `htaccess` file in this case, since the `Play` application is just running on a port and there is no website directory associated with it for apache2.

Comment: So where/how does the _“redirecting all the requests to it”_ part happen?

Comment: @CBroe It is documented in [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/HTTPServer) “When using an HTTP frontal server, request addresses are seen as coming from the HTTP server. In a usual set-up, where you both have the Play app and the proxy running on the same machine, the Play app will see the requests coming from 127.0.0.1."

Comment: @CBroe it seems like I have to configure [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I figured out I have to edit  `mydomain.com.conf` file under `sites_available`.